# Is it true that a metric compact is complete space?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Is it true that a metric compact is complete space?
I think that it is true.

Comment: Do you mean to ask wether a compact metric space is complete?

Comment: Yes it's my mistake, i edited

Comment: Yes, it is complete.  But not (usually) a linear space, so not a Banach space.

Comment: It seems that every real linear topological space $X$ contains a closed copy of $\mathbb R$. Thus $X$ cannot be a compact.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compact metric space $X$ is sequentially compact. Thus any Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence. But in a metric space, this is equivalent to the entire sequence being convergent.

Answer (score 2):

For more details see: Joshi, [Introduction To General Topology](http://books.google.ca/books?id=fvCpXrube5wC&pg=PA282&dq=every%20compact%20metric%20space%20is%20complete&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SrxyUaSaF-zi4AO_kIHIAQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=every%20compact%20metric%20space%20is%20complete&f=false), p282.